# Community for question related to 3GPP and Mobile Application Framework

Tags: feature-request, support, site-recommendation

As much as I understand, we don't have any community dedicated to Smart Card development. For example in SIM cards, we may require to ask questions in 3GPP standards or cattp or a proactive commands in SIM cards. It will be helpful for Toolkit Application developers for SIMs like me. It should also focus on payment smart cards like VISA or EMV.

Please mention if there is already any dedicated community site. Don't mention EE.SE or Network Security because they are helpful in these topics very rarely. We need a dedicated site for it.

Documentation pages are **[here](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/)**

Comment: You can find a list of sites here, http://stackexchange.com/sites and you can see all proposed sites here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/ (if you can't find a relevent one you can submit it here).